# How do you summarize data for a single field when it is one of multiple fields in GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| loc_id | pilot_ind | last_form_step_completed |
|--------|-----------|--------------------------|
| 9988   | non-pilot | 1                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 1                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 2                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 2                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 2                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 3                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 3                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 4                        |
| 9988   | non-pilot | 4                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 1                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 2                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 2                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 2                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 3                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 4                        |
| 1122   | non-pilot | 5                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 1                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 1                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 2                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 2                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 2                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 3                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 3                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 4                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 4                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 5544   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 1                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 2                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 2                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 3                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 3                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 3                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 4                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 4                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 4                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 5                        |
| 3344   | pilot     | 5                        |
```

I need to summarize it like this:

```
| pilot_ind | last_step_compl | total_count | total_per_pilot_ind | pct_pilot_ind_total |
|-----------|-----------------|-------------|---------------------|---------------------|
| non-pilot | 1               | 3           | 16                  | 18.8%               |
| non-pilot | 2               | 6           | 16                  | 37.5%               |
| non-pilot | 3               | 3           | 16                  | 18.8%               |
| non-pilot | 4               | 3           | 16                  | 18.8%               |
| non-pilot | 5               | 1           | 16                  | 6.3%                |
| pilot     | 1               | 3           | 26                  | 11.5%               |
| pilot     | 2               | 5           | 26                  | 19.2%               |
| pilot     | 3               | 5           | 26                  | 19.2%               |
| pilot     | 4               | 5           | 26                  | 19.2%               |
| pilot     | 5               | 8           | 26                  | 30.8%               |
```

I'm having trouble getting a grouped total for the pilot_ind in the total_per_pilot_ind field - I have tried using OVER (PARTITION BY), but the results are not correct because there are two fields in the GROUP BY clause. **Here is a link to the example data and current attempt: http://rextester.com/PCE62786**

```
select 
    r.pilot_ind
    ,r.last_form_step_completed
    ,count(*) total_count
    ,count(*) over ()
from
    results r
group by
    r.pilot_ind
    ,r.last_form_step_completed
order by 1,2
```

***EDIT:*** ***Is there a way to do this in one query?***

Comment: How `16` and `26` values in `total_per_pilot_ind` column were calculated in your example ?

Comment: I have edited the post to include the entire table. The table and data can be found in the rextester link as well. total_per_pilot_ind is a count of all rows for each value of the pilot_ind field (either pilot or non-pilot). By extension, pct_pilot_ind_total is calculated as (total_count / total_per_pilot_ind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT *,
      sum(total_count) over(partition by pilot_ind) As total_per_pilot_ind,
      round(100.0 * total_count / sum(total_count) over(partition by pilot_ind) ,1)
        as pct_pilot_ind_total
FROM (
select 
    r.pilot_ind
    ,r.last_form_step_completed
    ,count(*) total_count
from
    results r
group by
    r.pilot_ind
    ,r.last_form_step_completed
) x
order by 1,2
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0f411/5

Answer (score 0):

you could use a left join

```
  select 
      t.pilot_ind
      , t.last_form_step_completed
      , sum(a.last_form_step_completed) total_count
  from ( 
  select distinct pilot_ind, last_form_step_completed
  from my_table ) t 
  left join my_table a on t.pilot_ind = a.pilot_ind 
      and t.last_form_step_completed = a.last_form_step_completed
  group by t.pilot_ind
      , t.last_form_step_completed
```

(is not clear how you get the two last column in your sample .. so i omit them )

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.pilot_id, a.last_step, a.total_count, b.total_per_pilot_ind,
(a.total_count/ b.total_per_pilot_ind)*100 as Per_tage
from
(
select pilot_ind, last_form_step_completed as last_step, count(*) as total_count
from table1
group by pilot_ind, last_form_step_completed
) a,
(
select pilot_ind, sum(last_form_step_completed) as total_per_pilot_ind
from table1
group by pilot_id
) b
where a.pilot_ind=b.pilot_ind
```